# Event собитие на slick slider(slick.next,slick.prev)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Верстка мобильной версии `slick slider`.

Есть 6 блоков с картинками, данные блоки заключены в `slick slider`.
У каждого из 6 блоков имеется скрытый `div` с определенным контентом, который располагается чуть ниже изображений.

У `slick slider` присутствуют стрелки `.slick-next & .slick-prev`.
Отображение `slick slider` задано на экране `480px(slidesToShow: 1, slidesToScroll: 1)`

Проблема заключается в том, чтобы показывать скрытый контент под определенным слайдом только на клик стрелок, т.е. при первоначальной загрузке страницы у меня показывается первый блок с контентом ниже, далее я тапаю на `.slick-next` и у меня показывается следующий слайд и контент меняется на контент второго слайда, а первый контент скрывается и далее если листать слайдер(пальцем) через `draggable`, чтобы контент тоже менялся.

На данный момент контент не меняется при клике на стрелки и обычным свайпом тоже не меняется.

[Ссылка на fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsuynrto/)

```
    <div class="responsive_mob sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1">
<div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box1"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a></div>
<div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box2"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a></div>
<div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box3"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a></div>
<div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box4"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a></div>
<div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box5"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a></div>
<div class="picture1"><a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box6"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a></div>
</div>
<p class="btsc_text_af_cat_pic">Выберите категорию</p>

<div class="dropdn_menu_mob">
<div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob active" id="box1"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic1" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/CJXcjv0/pic-1.jpg" /></a></div>
<div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box2"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic2" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/rbKt7Kh/pic-2.jpg" /></a> </div>
<div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box3"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic2" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/qWvwGFK/pic-3.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box4"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic3" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/GTQPzL4/pic-4.jpg" /></a> </div>
<div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box5"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic5 обувь" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/Srx3Y1B/pic-5.jpg" /> </a></div>
<div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box6"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic6" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/SJQ4WzS/pic-6.jpg" /> </a></div>
</div>



 jQuery('.slick-prev').click(function(){
    jQuery('#box1').hide();
    jQuery('#box2').show();

});


jQuery('.slick-next').click(function(){
    var $current = jQuery('.block-of-text-mob.active');
    jQuery('.block-of-text-mob').removeClass('active');
    $current.next().addClass('active');
});


         jQuery('.responsive_mob').slick({
                dots: false,
                speed: 300,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: true,
                 infinite: false,
                responsive: [{
                        breakpoint: 1024,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 4,
                            slidesToScroll: 3,
                            infinite: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        breakpoint: 600,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 1,
                            slidesToScroll: 1,
                            infinite: false
                        }
                    }, {
                        breakpoint: 480,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 1,
                            slidesToScroll: 1,
                            infinite: false
                        }
                    }

                ]
            });






    .block-of-text.active{
        height: auto;
        }

        .picture1 {
            transition:0.5s;
          border:0;
          width:50px;
  height:150px;
        }

        .slick-slide img{

        }

        .btsc_main_pic{
            margin-top: 40px;
        }

        .btsc_txt{
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1{
max-width: 768px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 50px;

margin-top: 123px;
}

.plus_mob{

}

.dropdn_menu_mob{
display:block;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1 img{
    width: 75%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.block-of-text-mob:not(.active){
  display:none;
}

        .picture1 img {
          -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
          transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }


        .btsc_txt p{
          height: 77px;
          font-family: Roboto;
          font-size: 20px;
          font-weight: 300;
          font-style: normal;
          font-stretch: normal;
          line-height: 1.2;
          letter-spacing: normal;
          text-align: center;
          color: #2d2d2d;
        }

        .shadow_pics{
        position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 105px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    margin-right: 24px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
        }

        .btsc_text_af_cat_pic{
        font-family: Roboto;
          font-size: 20px;
          font-weight: 300;
          font-style: normal;
          font-stretch: normal;
          line-height: 1.05;
          letter-spacing: normal;
          text-align: left;
          color: #000000;
            margin-top: 43px;
            margin-bottom: 43px;

        }

.shadow_pics:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

        .picture1 img{

        }
         .block-of-text{
         margin-left:15px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        .btsc_first_elem{
            text-align: left;
            margin-left: 209px;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

        .svg_spisok{
        float: left;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .txt_left_p{
        font-family: Roboto;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 300;
          font-style: normal;
          font-stretch: normal;
          line-height: 1.25;
          letter-spacing: normal;
          color: #354656;
        }


        .txt_left_second_p{
        font-family: Roboto;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-style: normal;
          font-stretch: normal;
          line-height: 1.14;
          letter-spacing: normal;
          color: #222124;
        margin-top: 13px;
        margin-left: 44px;
        }


        .txt_right_p{
        font-family: Roboto;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 300;
          font-style: normal;
          font-stretch: normal;
          line-height: 1.25;
          letter-spacing: normal;
          color: #354656;
        }



        .btsc_second_elem{
        margin-left: 719px;
            margin-top: -67px;
            text-align: left;
        }


        .svg_mestopolojenie{
        float: left;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }


        .txt_right_second_p{
        font-family: Roboto;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-style: normal;
          font-stretch: normal;
          line-height: 1.14;
          letter-spacing: normal;
          color: #222124;
            margin-top: 13px;
            margin-left: 45px;
        }

        .slick-prev,
                .slick-next {
             font-size: 0;
            line-height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 44%;
            display: block;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            padding: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
            transform: translate(0,-50%);
            cursor: pointer;
            color: transparent;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            background: transparent;
            z-index: 3;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear,right top,left top,from(hsla(0,0%,100%,0)),to(#fff));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right,hsla(0,0%,100%,0),#fff);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(right,hsla(0,0%,100%,0),#fff);
            background: linear-gradient(270deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,0),#fff);
        }




        .slick-prev:before,.slick-next:before{
        display: block;
            content: "";
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
            font-size: 0;
            -webkit-transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
            -o-transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
            transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
            -webkit-transition-property: height,width;
            -o-transition-property: height,width;
            transition-property: height,width;
            border-radius: 50%;
        opacity: .9;
        }


        .slick-prev:before{
        background: #ececec;
        content:"<";
        }


        .slick-next:before{
        background: #ececec;
        content:">" 
        }


                .sum_rel_last {
                    margin-right: -12px!important;
                }


                .sum_rel_wide_slider {
                    margin: 16px auto;
                    width: calc(100% - 80px);
                }

                .sum_rel_wide_slider img {
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .sum_rel_dsk_img {
                    display: block;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .sum_rel_mob_img {
                    display: none;
                }

                .sum_rel_wide_slider_mob {
                    display: block;
                }

        .slick-next{
        right: -5px;
        }

              .slick-prev{
        left: -63px;
        }

                .slick-slide {
                    display: none;
                    float: left;
                    height: auto;
                    min-height: 1px;
                    outline:none;
                }

        .slick-slide a {
            outline: none;
        }

                .slick-prev:hover,
                .slick-prev:focus,
                .slick-next:hover,
                .slick-next:focus {
                    color: #000;
                    outline: none;
                    background: #e2e2e2;
                    */
                }

                .slick-prev:hover,
                .slick-prev:focus,
                .slick-next:hover,
                .slick-next:focus {
                    color: #000;
                    outline: none;
                    background: transparent;
                }



        .slick-prev.hidden,
        .slick-next.hidden {
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events:none;
        }

        .slick-disabled {
        display: none !important;
          pointer-events:none;
        }


                .slick-slide div {
                    width: 90%
                }



        @media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
            .slick-next{
           right: 25px;
            }
            }



           @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
            .slick-next{
           right: 7px;
            }
            }




            @media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
            .InD_wrapper {
            float: none;
            width:100%;
            }
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

            .sum_rel_wide_blk {
            display:none;

            }

            .sum_rel_wide_slider_mob{
            display:block;
            }

             .sum_rel_wide_slider_mob img {
                        width: 75%;
                    margin-bottom: 30px;
               margin: 0 auto;

                    }

             .sum_rel_mob_img {
                        width: 100%;
                        display: block;
                    }
            @media screen and (max-width: 414px) {

            .slick-next{
           right: 27px;

            }
        .slick-prev{
            left: 0px;
        }
            .slick-prev, .slick-next{
        top: 61%;
        }

        .sum_rel_wide_slider_mob img{
        margin-top:89px;
        }

.shadow_pics{
       margin-right: 19px;
    margin-left: -5.5px;
}
        .sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1{
display:block;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob{
display:none;
}

.dropdn_menu_mob{
display:block;
}

.dropdn_menu{
display:none;
}


            }

        @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {

            .slick-next{
           right: 3px;

            }
            }

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во время навешивания событий нажатия на кнопку, элементов `.slick-prev` и `.slick-next` еще не существует.

Есть три способа решения.

1. Навесить обработчик после инициализации (самый плохой).
2. Делегирование событий (плохой).
3. Использовать события самого слайдера при смене слайда (лучший).

Первый способ:

```js
jQuery('.responsive_mob').slick({
  dots: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: false,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      infinite: true
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: false
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: false
    }
  }]
});

jQuery('.slick-prev').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('#box1').hide();
  jQuery('#box2').show();
});
jQuery('.slick-next').on('click', function() {
  var $current = jQuery('.block-of-text-mob.active');
  jQuery('.block-of-text-mob').removeClass('active');
  $current.next().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.block-of-text.active {
  height: auto;
}

.picture1 {
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
}

.btsc_main_pic {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.btsc_txt {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1 {
  max-width: 768px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 123px;
}

.plus_mob {}

.dropdn_menu_mob {
  display: block;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1 img {
  width: 75%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block-of-text-mob:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}

.block-of-text {
  margin-left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btsc_first_elem {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 209px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.svg_spisok {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.txt_left_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #354656;
}

.txt_left_second_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.14;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #222124;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-left: 44px;
}

.txt_right_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #354656;
}

.btsc_second_elem {
  margin-left: 719px;
  margin-top: -67px;
  text-align: left;
}

.svg_mestopolojenie {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.txt_right_second_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.14;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #222124;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 44%;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 3;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0)), to(#fff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), #fff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), #fff);
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), #fff);
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -o-transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -o-transition-property: height, width;
  transition-property: height, width;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .9;
}

.slick-prev:before {
  background: #ececec url(https://www.auchan.ru/pokupki/media/uploads/strelka_Left_150519.svg) no-repeat 50%;
}

.slick-next:before {
  background: #ececec url(https://www.auchan.ru/pokupki/media/uploads/strelka_right_150519.svg) no-repeat 50%;
}

.sum_rel_last {
  margin-right: -12px!important;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider {
  margin: 16px auto;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider img {
  width: 100%;
}

.sum_rel_dsk_img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.sum_rel_mob_img {
  display: none;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob {
  display: block;
}

.slick-next {
  right: -5px;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: -63px;
}

.slick-slide {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 1px;
  outline: none;
}

.slick-slide a {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus {
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  */
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus {
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.slick-prev.hidden,
.slick-next.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-disabled {
  display: none !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-slide div {
  width: 90%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css">
<div class="responsive_mob sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1">
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box1"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box2"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box3"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box4"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box5"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box6"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="btsc_text_af_cat_pic">Выберите категорию</p>

<div class="dropdn_menu_mob">
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob active" id="box1">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic1" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/CJXcjv0/pic-1.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box2">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic2" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/rbKt7Kh/pic-2.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box3">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic2" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/qWvwGFK/pic-3.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box4">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic3" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/GTQPzL4/pic-4.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box5">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic5 обувь" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/Srx3Y1B/pic-5.jpg" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box6">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic6" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/SJQ4WzS/pic-6.jpg" /> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Второй способ:

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.slick-prev', function() {
  jQuery('#box1').hide();
  jQuery('#box2').show();
});
jQuery(document).on('click', '.slick-next', function() {
  var $current = jQuery('.block-of-text-mob.active');
  jQuery('.block-of-text-mob').removeClass('active');
  $current.next().addClass('active');
});
jQuery('.responsive_mob').slick({
  dots: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: false,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      infinite: true
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: false
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: false
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
.block-of-text.active {
  height: auto;
}

.picture1 {
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
}

.btsc_main_pic {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.btsc_txt {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1 {
  max-width: 768px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 123px;
}

.plus_mob {}

.dropdn_menu_mob {
  display: block;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1 img {
  width: 75%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block-of-text-mob:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}

.block-of-text {
  margin-left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btsc_first_elem {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 209px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.svg_spisok {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.txt_left_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #354656;
}

.txt_left_second_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.14;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #222124;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-left: 44px;
}

.txt_right_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #354656;
}

.btsc_second_elem {
  margin-left: 719px;
  margin-top: -67px;
  text-align: left;
}

.svg_mestopolojenie {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.txt_right_second_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.14;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #222124;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 44%;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 3;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0)), to(#fff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), #fff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), #fff);
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), #fff);
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -o-transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -o-transition-property: height, width;
  transition-property: height, width;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .9;
}

.slick-prev:before {
  background: #ececec url(https://www.auchan.ru/pokupki/media/uploads/strelka_Left_150519.svg) no-repeat 50%;
}

.slick-next:before {
  background: #ececec url(https://www.auchan.ru/pokupki/media/uploads/strelka_right_150519.svg) no-repeat 50%;
}

.sum_rel_last {
  margin-right: -12px!important;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider {
  margin: 16px auto;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider img {
  width: 100%;
}

.sum_rel_dsk_img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.sum_rel_mob_img {
  display: none;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob {
  display: block;
}

.slick-next {
  right: -5px;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: -63px;
}

.slick-slide {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 1px;
  outline: none;
}

.slick-slide a {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus {
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  */
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus {
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.slick-prev.hidden,
.slick-next.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-disabled {
  display: none !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-slide div {
  width: 90%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css">
<div class="responsive_mob sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1">
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box1"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box2"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box3"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box4"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box5"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box6"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="btsc_text_af_cat_pic">Выберите категорию</p>

<div class="dropdn_menu_mob">
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob active" id="box1">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic1" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/CJXcjv0/pic-1.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box2">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic2" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/rbKt7Kh/pic-2.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box3">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic2" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/qWvwGFK/pic-3.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box4">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic3" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/GTQPzL4/pic-4.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box5">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic5 обувь" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/Srx3Y1B/pic-5.jpg" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box6">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic6" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/SJQ4WzS/pic-6.jpg" /> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Третий способ:

```js
jQuery('.responsive_mob').slick({
  dots: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: false,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: true
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: false
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      infinite: false
    }
  }]
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  var $current = jQuery('.block-of-text-mob.active');
  jQuery('.block-of-text-mob').removeClass('active');
  $current.next().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.block-of-text.active {
  height: auto;
}

.picture1 {
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
}

.btsc_main_pic {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.btsc_txt {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1 {
  max-width: 768px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 123px;
}

.plus_mob {}

.dropdn_menu_mob {
  display: block;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1 img {
  width: 75%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block-of-text-mob:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}

.block-of-text {
  margin-left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btsc_first_elem {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 209px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.svg_spisok {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.txt_left_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #354656;
}

.txt_left_second_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.14;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #222124;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-left: 44px;
}

.txt_right_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #354656;
}

.btsc_second_elem {
  margin-left: 719px;
  margin-top: -67px;
  text-align: left;
}

.svg_mestopolojenie {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.txt_right_second_p {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.14;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #222124;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 44%;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 3;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0)), to(#fff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), #fff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), #fff);
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0), #fff);
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -o-transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  transition: .2s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -o-transition-property: height, width;
  transition-property: height, width;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .9;
}

.slick-prev:before {
  background: #ececec url(https://www.auchan.ru/pokupki/media/uploads/strelka_Left_150519.svg) no-repeat 50%;
}

.slick-next:before {
  background: #ececec url(https://www.auchan.ru/pokupki/media/uploads/strelka_right_150519.svg) no-repeat 50%;
}

.sum_rel_last {
  margin-right: -12px!important;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider {
  margin: 16px auto;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider img {
  width: 100%;
}

.sum_rel_dsk_img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.sum_rel_mob_img {
  display: none;
}

.sum_rel_wide_slider_mob {
  display: block;
}

.slick-next {
  right: -5px;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: -63px;
}

.slick-slide {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 1px;
  outline: none;
}

.slick-slide a {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus {
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  */
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus {
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.slick-prev.hidden,
.slick-next.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-disabled {
  display: none !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-slide div {
  width: 90%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css">
<div class="responsive_mob sum_rel_wide_slider_mob1">
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box1"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box2"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box3"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box4"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box5"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/c1yQ7Pk/pic-plus.png" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="picture1">
    <a class="js-open-box-mob" href="#/" data-target="#box6"><img class="pic1_img change_pic plus_mob" src="https://i.ibb.co/phfVDVq/pic-minus.png" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="btsc_text_af_cat_pic">Выберите категорию</p>

<div class="dropdn_menu_mob">
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob active" id="box1">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic1" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/CJXcjv0/pic-1.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box2">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic2" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/rbKt7Kh/pic-2.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box3">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic2" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/qWvwGFK/pic-3.jpg"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box4">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic3" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/GTQPzL4/pic-4.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box5">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic5 обувь" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/Srx3Y1B/pic-5.jpg" /> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="js-block-of-text-mob block-of-text-mob" id="box6">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="pic6" class="pic1_img shadow_pics" src="https://i.ibb.co/SJQ4WzS/pic-6.jpg" /> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: здравствуйте, как я понял 3 вариант самый оптимальный, но если кликать на стрелку влево, то отображается следующий слайд, а не предыдущий

Comment: Т.е. 1 слайду соответствует 1 контент, 2слайд=2 итд, они получается все уникальные

Comment: @DmitriyAndreevich я не писал логику по определению направления перехода (вперед или назад), потому что у вас в вопросе ее нету. Думаю, вы сами сможете такое написать.

Comment: вот я как раз и не понял как отобразить ее в коде

Comment: @DmitriyAndreevich чего именно вы не поняли? У вас вопрос немножко про другое был.

Comment: я понимаю, что про другое, но не понимаю как корректно повесить логику на переключение слайдов, чтобы при клике на предыдущий слайд, у меня отображался предыдущий контент под слайдом, а сейчас при клике на предыдущий отображается контент следующего слайда, в этом и есть проблема(

Comment: }).on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  var mySlideNumber = nextSlide;
  jQuery('.slick-slide').removeClass('slick-active');
  jQuery('.slick-slide').eq(mySlideNumber).addClass('slick-active');
}).on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){   
   jQuery('.js-block-of-text-mob').hide();
   jQuery('.js-block-of-text-mob[data-id=' + (currentSlide + 1) + ']').show();
});     -  Вот написал код, который с по data-id должен менять слайды, почему-то при нажатии на кнопку у меня весь контент становится display:none;

Comment: @DmitriyAndreevich вы посмотрите, чему равен `currentSlide`. Какой `.block-of-text-mob` должен показываться, если на экране четыре `.js-open-box-mob` отображается?